# Convert Color-Referenced Array to PNG/JPG

Tags: python, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray, python-xarray

I have loaded a GeoTIFF into an ndarray through rioxarray, converted units, and applied a custom color ramp with Matplotlib to the normalized array. This looks as follows:

```
import rioxarray as rxr, geopandas as gpd
from matplotlib import cm, colors as clr

with rxr.open_rasterio(file, lock=False, mask_and_scale=True) as da:
    da = da.rio.reproject(dst_crs)
    data = (da.data[0] * 1.8) + 32
    bounds = da.rio.bounds()
    minlon, minlat, maxlon,  maxlat = bounds

values = [-70, -60, -50, -40, -30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120]
norm_da = (data - min(values)) / (max(values) - min(values))
colorlist = [(0, '#b7b1b9d9'),(0.05, '#4e008bd9'), (0.11, '#f03c99d9'), (0.16, '#ed77b8d9'),(0.21, '#d0b6d9d9'),(0.26, '#97f7f7d9'),(0.32, '#1674f0d9'),(0.365, '#3727a1d9'),(0.366, '#520980d9'),(0.42, '#f000bcd9'),(0.47, '#9c060ed9'), (0.53, '#ffffffd9'), (0.57, '#1279ffd9'), (0.61, '#00f0f0d9'), (0.65, '#befa00d9'), (0.69, '#ffff00d9'), (0.73, '#ff8000d9'), (0.77, '#f51400d9'), (0.82, '#800000d9'), (0.88, '#732c45d9'), (0.94, '#fc9090d9'), (1, '#fcf7f7d9')]
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(values),vmax=max(values))
cm = clr.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('TempRamp',colorlist, N=256)
color_da = cm(norm_da)
```

Previously, I would use GDAL's gdaldem with the color-relief argument to generate a color ramp to the GeoTIFF, which was then exported to a PNG. Is it possible to save this color-normalized array to a georeferenced JPG or PNG strictly in Python?